# Angular proxy conf not appending endpoint

Tags: angular, proxy

I am running with a proxy conf and making a request to my endpoint at `/ntc/event`

```
return this.http.get<Array<NTCEvent>>("/ntc/event", {
  params: queryParams, headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
});
```

The proxy conf file should forward the request to http://localhost:1880/ntc/event
. Therefor I have the following entry in my proxy.conf:

```
{
    "/ntc": {
        "target": "http://localhost:1880",
        "secure": "false",
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Basic dXNlcjpVc2VyMSE="
        }
    }
}
```

When the call is made through the application the following error is logged on the server:

`[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/ntc/event?SiteId=P2&DateFrom=2023-03-02T23:00:00.000Z&DateTo=2023-03-03T23:00:00.000Z to http://localhost:1880/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

It seems like the angular app is just requesting against http://localhost:1880 without appending any endpoint or query parameters resulting in an error.

When I run without the proxy conf with the full URL and authentication in the `http.get`, then everything is working fine.

Comment: This looks like valid configuration to me. Also this is default error message, it doesn't display the full url it's trying to redirect to. Are you sure that endpoint is accessible? Can you open it in the browser?

Comment: @displayName; yes I am able to get a valid response from `http://localhost:1880/ntc/event?SiteId=P2&DateFrom=2023-03-02T23:00:00.000Z&DateTo=2023-03-03T23:00:00.000Z` using the provided basic authentication

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the correct proxy setup as shown in [Building and serving Angular apps](https://angular.io/guide/build)?

More specifically, check if your proxyConfig is set up here...

> In the CLI configuration file, angular.json, add the proxyConfig
> option to the serve target:

```
content_copy
…
  "architect": {
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      },
…
```

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't be seeing the debug messages of the proxy